# MySQL syntax-error in nested loop block. Can't find the error.

Tags: mysql

I tried to code a simple nested loop as a mysql block. The server got me a syntax error, but i can't find it.

Does anybody see it?

The error message was: 
Query: END LOOP get_invoice

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END LOOP get_invoice' at line 1

```
BEGIN 
        DECLARE v_id INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE v_finished1 INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE invoices_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT id_invoice FROM invoice i WHERE invoice_type = 'RE' AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM invoice ma WHERE invoice_type = 'MA' AND ma.origin = i.id_invoice);        
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished1 = 1;
    OPEN invoices_cursor;
    get_invoice: LOOP
        FETCH invoices_cursor INTO v_id;

        IF v_finished1 = 1 THEN          
            CLOSE invoices_cursor;
            LEAVE get_invoice;
        END IF;  
        DECLARE v_finished2 INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE v_dunning_level INT DEFAULT 1;              
        DECLARE dunning_cursor CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT id_invoice FROM invoice ma WHERE invoice_type = 'MA' AND ma.origin = v_id ORDER BY `create` ASC;     
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished2 = 1;              
        OPEN dunning_cursor;
        get_dunnings: LOOP
            DECLARE v_id_dun BIGINT DEFAULT NULL;                       
            FETCH dunning_cursor INTO v_id_dun;         
            IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
                LEAVE get_dunnings;
            END IF;      
            UPDATE invoice SET dunning_level = v_dunning_level WHERE invoice_type = 'MA' AND id_invoice = v_id_dun;
            SET v_dunning_level = v_dunning_level + 1;                      
        END LOOP get_dunnings ;
        CLOSE dunning_cursor;

    END LOOP get_invoice ;
END;
```

Comment: What's your goal here that you're writing such a complicated piece of MySQL code?

Comment: It is a update script for the invoice table. We changed the logic how we save dunnings in this table...